# Use script output in Makefile, to be used in sed cmd and variable update

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I want to generate a random value within a given range and use the result to update a Makevariable as well as modify a file.

I tried using the below code, I do see the random value generated. But I am unable to use it in the sed/Make variable.

Makefile ::

```
ALL_CPU_IRQ = 1

all:
ifeq ($(ALL_CPU_IRQ),1)
        RANDINT=$(shell python -c 'from random import randint; print(randint(1,3));')
        @echo $(RANDINT)
override BLOCK_RUN_OPT  +=  +init_cpu=$(RANDINT)
        sed -i 's|asm_comp_opt_tl=|\0INIT_CPU=$(RANDINT),|' $(CURDIR)/asm_opt.txt
        @echo $(BLOCK_RUN_OPT)
endif
```

---

Output I observe is :

```
RANDINT=2
+init_cpu=
```

And asm_opt.txt :   asm_comp_opt=INIT_CPU=,

---

Expected output :

```
RANDINT=2
+init_cpu=2
```

And asm_opt.txt :   asm_comp_opt=INIT_CPU=2,

---

I am fairly new to Makefile. Any suggestions would be helpful. Apologies if it's a redundant question.

Comment: What is the expected output? And what output do you expect in the Makefile finally? Can you help us in that?

Comment: Sorry I missed it in main thread. Expected output :   BLOCK_RUN_OPT = +init_cpu=2  and asm_opt.txt ::   asm_comp_opt=INIT_CPU=2,

Comment: Hang on, is that code in a script? I don't see how it could function as well as it does in a makefile, whether it's in a rule or not.

Comment: @Beta :  It is part of rule of Makefile. I have updated the main thread, with full Makefile sample

Comment: If that is your full makefile, what is `BLOCK_RUN_OPT` for?

Comment: This is an excerpt for total makefile. I would want to use BLOCK_RUN_OPT further as arg to simv command

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
RANDINT=$(shell python -c 'from random import randint; print(randint(1,3));')
@echo $(RANDINT)
    override BLOCK_RUN_OPT  +=  +init_cpu=$(RANDINT)
@echo $(BLOCK_RUN_OPT)
sed -i 's|asm_comp_opt_=|\0INIT_CPU="$RANDINT",|' $(CURDIR)/asm_opt.txt
```

Comment: I tried below change, but issue remains the same.                                                                
      sed -i 's|asm_comp_opt_tl=|\0INIT_CPU="$(RANDINT)",|' $(CURDIR)/asm_opt.txt